# Sticky Footer in Css gets in the way of container, or creates extra space

Tags: html, css

Soooooo I'm making a sticky footer in Css. It doesn't work the way I want it to. The footer sticks to the bottom, but I also want 100% height for the page. This doesn't work, and I've tried a lot. Currently, the footer gets in the way of the container, and they overlap. If i give the container `margin-bottom: 70px;`, it creates extra unwanted space when the content is very small, making an unnecessary scrollbar.

Here's my code:

```
<html><head>

<style type='text/css'>

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: left;
    width: 800px;
    height: auto !important;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.bold-show {
    font-family: Helvectica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 96px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95);
    color: #eeeeee;
    padding: 50px;
}

#footer {
    position: relative;
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    margin-top: -70px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    color: #eeeeee;
}

#footer div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

</style>

</head><body>

<div class='container'>
    <div class='bold-show'>
    Donuts. Food for thought. This is my place, this fox will guide you. Random filler text for the win.
    </div>
</div>

<div id='footer'>
    <div>
        We support a free and open internet. 
    </div>
</div>

</body></html>
```

Also, this is not the actual site. Just testing to implement on real site.

Comment: have you tried this: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/? it works real nice.

Comment: Well, my sticky footer works fine, it's the rest of the page I can't get to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is what you are looking for:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <header></header>
  <div id="main"></div>
  <footer></footer>
</div>

body, html, #wrapper { height: 100%;  } /* Create space for elements to be 100% */
#wrapper { display: table; } /* Create a table-structure */
#wrapper > * { display: table-row; } /* All direct children behave as rows */
#wrapper > header, 
#wrapper > footer { min-height: 100px; } /* These must be at least 100px */
#main { height: 100%; } /* Let the mid section fill up the remaining space */
```

Comment: Thanks, what I really needed to make it work was the wrapper.